# Python watchdog - check if copy is complete before copy directory

Tags: python

Can someone please assist with this code. We have folders with subfolders and files downloaded in the "repo" directory periodically. We want to execute watchdog command to only copy/move the folders after download is complete.

```
import time, os, shutil, glob
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler

    
rootdir = "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test\\Repo"
destdir = "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test\\Dest\\"

def on_created(event):
    global rootdir
    global destdir
    global eiresdir
    global partners

    dir_manager.dir_list()
    partners2 =  list( dict.fromkeys(partners) )
    eires_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(event.src_path, "*.txt"))
   
    
    try:
        for list4 in partners2:
            if not os.path.exists(""+destdir+"" + str(list4)):
                os.mkdir(""+destdir+"" + str(list4))
            if event.is_directory:
                for x in partners2: 
                    if x in event.src_path:
                        shutil.copytree((event.src_path), os.path.join((""+destdir+"" + str(x)),event.src_path.replace(rootdir,(""+destdir+"" + str(x)))))
                        print(f"{event.src_path} has been created")          
    except:
        pass
           
    
my_event_handler.on_created = on_created
#my_event_handler.on_deleted = on_deleted
#my_event_handler.on_modified = on_modified

observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(my_event_handler, rootdir, recursive=True)



observer.start()
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
except:
    observer.stop()
observer.join()
```

Comment: What issue are u facing ?

Comment: copy of files is initiated before the downloading of files in the root directory is complete. This issue happens with files over 3gb in size

Comment: Where is the download happening. Can't u make it synchronous. Download and then immeidatly copy instead of periodically polling.

Comment: The only process that knows if the download is complete is the process that downloads. U will have to put a watchdog on the process of u want to do this periodically.